# jQuery validate select box with focusCleanup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate plugin to validate my form. So when a user clicks on submit button it validates the form.
Now if user clicks on any form element the error should be cleared until user leaves the input.

So from plugin documentation I know that focusCleanup is exactly what I am looking for.It works for all elements except drop downs.

Fix that work for all element but drop-downs
http://jsfiddle.net/paraselixir/sw87W/259/

### To fix this I have tried following settings for validation  plugin

```
    settings = {
        // global form validator settings
        errorClass : 'error',
        errorElement : 'span',
        onkeyup : false,
        .
        .    
        focusCleanup : true,
        onclick:false,
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Reference: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-select-box-with-focuscleanup

This solution has fixed the issue for dropdowns but now same issue is happening on checkboxes.

Fix that works for drop-downs but not for checkboxes

Fiddle Example :http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/257/

So I need a solution that works for all elements.

Comment: While providing an answer along with your question is generally good practice, you're still expected to follow all posting guidelines the same as if you were posting a stand-alone question.  In other words, you should have posted some code for a demo within your OP along with the description.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @sparky .I have attached the solution as a js fiddle. But this fix has caused same issue in checkbox. Are you able to provide any solution

Comment: You already answered your own question, and now you're asking a new followup question about your own answer.  As per my first comment, please clean this all up.

Comment: Very unclear.  The only difference between your two demos is the `onclick: false` option.  [As per documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onclick), the `onclick` option only affects radio and checkbox elements.  In other words, as far as `select` elements, both demos behave identically.

Comment: No sir! Check the difference.  submit the form then click on these elements

Comment: After submitting the form when you click on these elements, in http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/257/   error message hides when you click on select box

Answer (score 0):

> After submitting the form when you click on these elements, in `jsfiddle.net/sw87W/257` error message hides when you click on select box

Apparently, the `onclick` option also disables the `select`.  However, if you need the `onclick: false` option for the checkbox, then you'll need to write another handler for the select element...

```
$('[name="numbers"]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/d83oaa3v/**